# Failed to use the AWS greengrasssdk to get thing shadow with error code 404

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I want to collect some information with my sensor and analyze them  on greengrass core to decide whether send an e-mail by SES to me or not. Everything is ready except my connection between shadow and lambda, which is deployed on my greengrass core. When I try to get information from shadow, I can only get error code like this:

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Shadow Not Found",
  "timestamp": 1529392914
}
```

But actually, the shadow is updated continuously every second. Is there anything that I missed? Or can somebody give me some suggestion? Thanks all!

```
import greengrasssdk

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    seeeduino_client = greengrasssdk.client('iot-data')
    client = greengrasssdk.client('iot-data') # it's used for send data to "Iot Cloud"

    response = seeeduino_client.get_thing_shadow(thingName='Seeeduino_Cloud')
    client.publish(
                    topic='load/successed',
                    payload=response["payload"]
                    )
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim

How are you updating the shadow? Is it updated to IoT Core in the cloud, or it is updated to Greengrass Local shadow? These two are independent in GG.